# cursor.fetchall() throws index out or range error

Tags: python-3.6, cx-oracle, index-error

I have an issue which I am not sure where the root cause is:

I use python cx_Oracle to connect to an Oracle DB.

`cursor.fetchall()` returns me records in this format [(4352,)]

I want to retrieve the '4352' so i proceed to do this: `pk = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]`

However i get: `IndexError: list index out of range`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong since when i manually create this return object on my python console as such: `item = [(4352,)]`, I can retrieve the '4352' by calling `item[0][0]`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong.

In my code i did something like this:

```
print(cursor.fetchall()) # line 56
a = cursor.fetchall()[0][0] # line 57
```

At line 56, the output of [(4352,)] is correct.
However at line 57, the `cursor.fetchall()` becomes a []. This is because cursor.fetchall() is a generator. It has been automatically garbage-collected after line 56.

Therefore, if I wanted to extract out 4352 from the inner tuple, I had to call line 57 first and subsequently print(a) if I wanted to see the value of the return result from the database.

Comment: I meet this problem today and this answer worked for me in MS SQL database. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the list returned by the fetchall() statement?

It looks like the resulting list is empty.

Comment: Yes i am sure. I print out the result and got [(4532,)]

Comment: You mean you did **print(cursor.fetchall())**?

Comment: Yes, i printed out cursor.fetchall()